# Printing a float with the least possible digits after decimal point

Tags: python, string

Is there an elegant way to have a float→str output with eg zero or one digits?

8.5 should become '8.5', and 9.0 should become '9'.

Update. Well, to make it more precise, the way, that'll work for any float, and will output one digit save for the "integer" floats, which should be formatted as integers, id est without decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `str.format` with "General format" as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

```
In [1]: print('{:.9g}'.format(8.5))
8.5

In [2]: print('{:.9g}'.format(9.0))
9
```

Comment: You can also use formatted string literals in Python 3.6+, e.g. `f'{8.5:.9g}'`. +1

Comment: Alas: '{:.9g}'.format(123456789.1). But for my use case and for my possible inputs, this will work well: '{:.9g}'.format(round(8.55,1))

Answer (score 3):

With Python 3.6+ you should consider formatted string literals ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
x = 8.5
y = 9.0
z = 8.05

for i in (x, y, z):
    print(f'{i:.9g}')

8.5
9
8.05
```

Manually, you can define a function to compare `float` and `int` values:

```
def make_str(x):
    float_val = float(x)
    int_val = int(float_val)
    if float_val == int_val:
        return str(int_val)
    return str(float_val)

make_str(9.0)  # '9'
make_str(8.5)  # '8.5'
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now and it works well, but I'm interested in something more elegant:) the replace() answer looks nice.

Comment: @aikipooh, In that case, I'd phrase your original question more precisely. What are your concern(s)? Performance, number of lines of code, existence of a potential built-in that does the job?

Comment: um, I think elegance, something that's called pythonic way, I think there's no ready builtin, I've even looked into numpy. Just was interested to learn something new here, no real concerns and no real problem! Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: @aikipooh, I see, well for elegance I don't think anything beats formatted string literals (as per my update).

Comment: general format will fail in the case of very big number, it'll eat the fractional part… But thank you for the f-strings mention, nice thing to learn, going to happily change thereto from format():)

Comment: Formatted seems more elegant and working except something like `123456789.1`. But +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that for my use case I can use Decimal instead of float, setting it from strings, and it does the right thing™:

```
>>> 'value={}'.format(Decimal('5'))
'value=5'
>>> 'value={}'.format(Decimal('5.5'))
'value=5.5'
```

Comment: And when using string inputs like 5.0, ```Decimal('5.0').normalize()``` works.

Answer (score 0):

Just a `replace`:

```
>>> s = 8.5
>>> str(s).replace('.0', '')
8.5
>>> s = 9.0
>>> str(s).replace('.0', '')
9
```

Cases like `8.05` fail using `replace`. To handle such cases, if you want, use `re.sub`:

```
import re

s = 8.05
print(re.sub(r'\.0*$', '', str(s)))
# 8.05
```

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention the third case here for completeness: 8.55:) But yes, it's better than what I have now and will suit my needs too, because I have maximum 1 digit after the point. Oh, just occured to me: 8.05 will pose a problem.

Comment: What do you expect for `8.55`?

Comment: 8.5 would suffice, I've had no need for any intelligent rounding. So changing s to round(s,1) should fix it anyway, Both 8.55 and 8.05.